# Confusing about the pre-trend test suggested by Goodman-Bacon, 2019's note?

Tags: econometrics, difference-in-difference

[Goodman,  2019](http://goodman-bacon.com/pdfs/ddtiming.pdf) is a very famous paper decomposing the coefficients of staggered DiD.
Here I do not talk about the paper itself, I talk about the [note](https://cdn.vanderbilt.edu/vu-my/wp-content/uploads/sites/2318/2019/10/09023516/so_youve_been_told_dd_10_9_2019.pdf) accompanying with this paper.

Pre-trend testing with multiple periods and groups have been discussed as in the note of [Pischke,2005, page 7](https://econ.lse.ac.uk/staff/spischke/ec524/evaluation3.pdf). Pischke's way of pre-trend test is summarized at running the regression
$$y_{it} = \lambda_i + \delta_t +
\beta_{-2}D_{it} + \beta_{-1}D_{it} + \beta_1 D_{it} + \beta_2 D_{it}
+ \beta_3 D_{it} + \epsilon_{it}$$

> where $y$ is the outcome for individual $i$ at time $t$, $\lambda$ and
> $\delta$ are individual and time fixed effects

And then see how close $\beta_{-i}$ (i=1,2) to 0 and how $\beta_{j}$(j=1,2,3) varies. It is also used by a lot of papers and discussion in Cross Validated by [Andy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152735/what-is-the-best-way-to-visualize-difference-in-differences-multi-period-regre), [Thomas Bilach](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/526787/how-to-plot-the-graph-or-perform-a-formal-test-of-parallel-trends-for-generalize).

The thing is [Goodman, 2019, page 8](https://cdn.vanderbilt.edu/vu-my/wp-content/uploads/sites/2318/2019/10/09023516/so_youve_been_told_dd_10_9_2019.pdf) proposed a way of testing pre-trend, but the way he describe things quite ambiguous to me

[image]

The first two sentences seem to align with what Pischke, 2005 did above. **However, I do not understand what does the last three sentences mean?**